# number declared in vue data can't go under 0

Tags: vue.js

I've data which is also width in my project so everytime I click for example a `button` it will - my data number my code does perfectly but there's one thing, it can't go under 0 any soltuons?

```js
  data:{
    monsterHealth:100,
  },
  methods:{
    attack(){
      var max = 10
        var min = 3
        var damage = Math.max(Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1,  min)
      this.monsterHealth -= damage;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="monster">
      <h1>MONSTER</h1><div class="healthbar" :style="{width:monsterHealth + '%'}"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="attack" @click="attack">Attack</button>
```

Comment: do u want prevent go under 0?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo no, it's already prevented, I want to go under 0.

Comment: if my `monsterHealth` is for example -10 it's not really working

Comment: width size can't be negative